# How to enable shell_exec() function in CentOS 5.6?

Tags: php, centos

I am using CentOS 5.6.

When I google to find the answer about how to enable `shell_exec()` in CentOS 5.6 they answer as the following:

```
# nano /etc/php.ini
```

remove shell_exec from the `disable_functions` list. But in my php.ini file shows the following:

```
disable_functions =
```

How can I enable `shell_exec()` function in CentOS 5.6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your SELinux is disabled.

Comment: This is terrible answer

Answer (score 2):

Disable [`safe_mode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php) and `shell_exec` should be available.

Comment: safe_mode is disabled and shell_exec is not enabled... What should I do?

Comment: Well what exactly doesn't work then? Is there an error message when you use `shell_exec`?

Answer (score 0):

create a script contains the following

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

and see if there is other php.ini files

Comment: There is only one php.ini in /etc result of phpinfo();

Comment: I have two servers. The code is identical to both the servers. In one server it is running but in the other it is not running. Any other clue ?

Answer (score 0):

I found this in the Internet: 
disable_functions = ""